# Xamarin Android: Get HTML content

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

I have a WebView in which I display my site, in that site I have 3 pages in sequence, of those 3 pages I need to identify when the user is on the last page, and from that to get the html content that display that page.

I manage to do a WebViewClient in which i can now identify when the user is on the last page, the problem is that I don t know how to move pass that, I don 't know how to get the html content from that page.

This is what I have so far:

```
namespace WebViewExample
{
  [Activity(Label = "WebView", MainLauncher = true)]
  public class WebView : Activity
{
    Android.Webkit.WebView web_view;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.WebView);

        web_view = FindViewById<Android.Webkit.WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        web_view.LoadUrl(url);
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            int i = 0;
        }


    }




}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a c# class that contains methods to be called from javaScript
2. If your Android API level 17 or later, This class need annotate each JavaScript-callable method with [JavascriptInterface] and [Export]
3. Your WebView should call AddJavascriptInterface() method
4. The method of onPageFinished() will be called when page loading finished

This is code :

```
namespace WebViewTest{
[Activity(Label = "WebViewTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Android.Webkit.WebView web_view;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        web_view = FindViewById<Android.Webkit.WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        web_view.LoadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943265/xamarin-android-get-html-content");
        // 3. your WebView must call AddJavascriptInterface() method 
        web_view.AddJavascriptInterface(new InJavaScriptLocalObj(), "local_obj");
    }
}

public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    private int count;
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
    {
        base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        count++;
        //page count 
        //  4.The method of onPageFinished() will be called when page loading finished
        if (count == 2)
        {
            view.LoadUrl("javascript:window.local_obj.showSource('<head>'+"
            + "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
//1. Create a c# class that contains methods to be called from javaScript.
//The Method is that called in javaScript.
public sealed class InJavaScriptLocalObj : Java.Lang.Object
{
    //2.if your Android API level 17 or later, 
    //This class must annotate each JavaScript-callable method with [JavascriptInterface] and [Export]
    [Export]
    [JavascriptInterface]

    public void showSource(string html)
    {
        // System.out.println("====>html=" + html);
    }
}
```

}